# Odoo PoS dropdown from Many2one (widget.pos?)

Tags: javascript, widget, odoo, odoo-8, point-of-sale

I want to add a dropdown from a Many2one I've created to the pos.xml file (I know how to inherit from this), can someone help me with this?

I saw in the code that for every dropdown they used **widget.pos.*name***, but this I can't seem to find it anywhere. Here is an example for countries (here I want to replace it by my variable).

```
                <select class='detail client-address-country' name='country_id'>
                    <option value=''>None</option>
                    <t t-foreach='widget.pos.countries' t-as='country'>
                        <option t-att-value='country.id' t-att-selected="partner_country_id ? ((country.id === partner.country_id[0]) ? true : undefined) : undefined"> 
                            <t t-esc='country.name'/>
                        </option>
                    </t>
               </select>
```

I don't know where the t-foreach='widget.pos.countries' comes from and how I can manage this for my own variable called "domain" which is part of a class "domainnames". And called from a Many2one from res.partner

Comment: Please provide some example code which demonstrates your problem.

Comment: refer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890929/odoo-pos-create-a-dropdown-list i think it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your Que: I saw in the code that for every dropdown they used widget.pos.name, but this I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Answer: widget.pos.name come from the In **POS**, **models.js** **line No: 130**., Here **Server side model** are loaded. This is the list of the models that need to be loaded from the server. in your custom module you can also load other models according to your requirement.

Que: I don't know where the t-foreach='widget.pos.countries' comes from and how I can manage this for my own variable?

Answer: For Country widget, it comes from **models.js line No: 178**, **model:'res.country'** loaded from the server. 
In **line 180**: You can see that in loaded function they define **countries**(loaded: **function**(self,**countries**)) // You can give any naming conventions here.
So you can directly pass that **function parameters** in your (Many2One Field) **xml** file.

**Example:** 
Write in your **JS File** of custom module:

```
    module.PosModel.prototype.models.push({ //loaded model
    model:  'res.partner',
        fields: ['partner_id','name'],
        loaded: function(self,partners){ //pass parameters
        self.partners = partners;

    },
});
```

**In XML File:**

```
       <div class='client-detail'>
        <span class='label'>Partner</span>
            <select class='detail client-partner' name='partner_id'>
                 <option value=''>None</option>
                    <t t-foreach='widget.pos.partners' t-as='partner'>
                      <option t-att-value='partner.id' t-att-selected="partner_partner_id ? ((partner.id === partner.partner_id) ? true : undefined) : undefined">

                       <t t-esc='partner.name'/>
                   </option>
                  </t>
              </select>
    </div>
```

So, Just like that: In your js, you can load any of the model here and fetch data in your XML file. 
Hope this will help you..!!!
Thanks...!!!

Comment: worked briliantly! thank you very much. Now the only thing is when I select something from the dropdown and save the new customer (I see this is updated in the database). But when I now want to edit the customer the dropdown shows "None" as default, how can u change this